# Set timezone for the Cron expression

Tags: java, cron

I have a scheduler which saves the schedule as a Cron expression.

My server (which is not local) is in UTC timezone, and my system can be in any timezone. In the process of saving the Cron, I'm 100% sure that the cron expression is saved exactly as the user timezone. (if user selects 9AM in the schedule form, it directly goes into the Cron expression, without any conversion), but surprisingly the jobs runs on the exact time that it should run ! Now, my best guess is that somewhere the quartz gets the user's time zone. Is it possible to set the user's timezone for the engine which runs the cron expression instead of converting each piece of information (days of week, hour in day, days in month, etc.) from user's time zone to UTC ?